# Сan I create a sub-group for headers that will not create a new line from above but occupy part of the grouped headers instead?

Tags: sas, sas-ods, proc-report

To better explain what I need, I added a picture. I want to get option 1 instead of option 2 which is usually created with `column var1 ("Title for both vars" var 2 var 3) var4`

The only thing I came up with was creating subgroups also for other variables and then distributing text between the "subgroup" title and the defining title like:

```
`column ("part1" var1) ("Title for both vars" var 2 var 3) ("part1" var4)
define var1/display "part2"
...
define va4/display "part2"`
```

But it looks not convenient at all and I am sure that there should be a more logical solution but I can't find it

[image]

Comment: You might be able to do it by adapting the ODS tagset via PROC TEMPLATE. Or, in the case of ODS HTML, reading it (the HTML output) back into a datastep and manipulating the HTML tags to include `rowspan='2'` on the first and last `td` elements.

Comment: You can get the visual effect by turning off bottom borders in the first cells of columns 1 & 4 under option 2 as well.